# Contact information (including email) for all US state legislators

Tags: usa, legal, state

Where can I find a single list containing the contact information (including email address) of state legislators for all 50 US states, ideally broken down by state and chamber (most states have a House and Senate, just like the federal government) and including US territories and possessions?

To clarify, I am referring to the group of people who meet in each state's capital city, not the people who meet in Washington DC to represent their state.

I've found several sites that have information for individual states. Some examples:

- https://www.cga.ct.gov/asp/menu/hlist.asp (CT)
- http://www.gencourt.state.nh.us/house/members/housemembersemail.aspx (NH)
- MN is split by chamber:

  - http://www.house.leg.state.mn.us/members/hmem.asp
  - http://www.senate.mn/members/

In theory, I could try finding pages like this for all states, but I'm sure someone has already compiled such a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Open States](https://openstates.org/) has all of this information. [Here's contact information, including email](https://openstates.org/va/legislators/VAL000055/betsy-b-carr/) for one of my senators.
You could scrape them or [use their API](http://docs.openstates.org/en/latest/api/).

Comment: Thanks, their bulk download page https://openstates.org/downloads/ does exactly what I need!

Comment: lol. sorry, forgot about bulk download